# NoMethodError in Posts#show geocoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm using the `geocoder` gem. I'm getting a method error in `posts#show` on line 8. It's basically saying that longitude is undefined.

[image]

**_form,html.erb**

```
 <%= form_with(model: post, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
       <h2><%= pluralize(post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this 
    post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :date %>
    <%= form.datetime_select :date, id: :post_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_area :name, id: :post_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="action">
    <%= form.label :address %>
    <%= form.text_area :address, id: "post_address" %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :user_id %>
    <%= form.number_field :user_id, id: :post_user_id, value: current_user.id %>

  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, id: :post_description %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 geocoded_by :address
 after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
 <p> where: <%=@post.longitude %>, <%=@post.latitude%></p>
```

**posts_controller_rb**

```
def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:date, :user_id, :description, :name, :address)
end
load_and_authorize_resource
```

I'm not exactly sure what the error is but I'm sure there's something wrong. I've tried looking into this problem but with no success. I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `model` must have two attributes (database columns) for storing `latitude` and `longitude` coordinates.

**So you should add those columns via `migration`:**

```
rails generate migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToPost latitude:float longitude:float
```

**Then migrate DB:**

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not migrated these two columns so run a command for migrating these two columns it looks like this

```
rails g migration AddLatitudeAndLongitudeToPost latitude:float longitude:float
```

then run

```
rake db:migrate #=> or rails
```

See this [`Object Geocoding`](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#object-geocoding)